# mySQL query to postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, syntax

I am new to PostgreSQL. while following one article which is on MySQL I am facing one challenge that the mySQL query is throwing error in PostgreSQL. Can anyone tel me the solution for this.

MySQL query is

```
CREATE TABLE "sessions" (
"id" varchar(128) 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
"expires" int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
"data" text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

What will be the similar query for PostgreSQL

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.htm)?

Comment: What kind of values do you store in the expires column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how important the binary collations are for what you are doing.  But this will probably work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id varchar(128) primary key,
    expires int NOT NULL check(expires >= 0),
    data text 
) ;
```